# Angular + Requirejs - each data is repeated twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am running Angular under Requirejs, but I have this multiple occurrence where the data in the controller class is repeated twice. Unless I remove `ng-app="myApp"` from the `div`. Why?

welcomeController.js,

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.controller('welcomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
        //your minsafe controller 
        $scope.message = "Message from WelcomeController"; 
        console.log($scope.message); // it is repeated twice here.
    }]);
});
```

HTML,

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/vendors/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">

        <div ng-controller="welcomeController">

            {{message}}

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

main.js,

```
require.config({
    //baseUrl: "",

    // alias libraries paths.  Must set 'angular'
    paths: {
        'domReady': 'vendors/requirejs-domready/domReady',
        'angular': 'vendors/angular/angular',
        'angular-route': 'vendors/angular-route/angular-route',
        'jquery': 'vendors/jquery/dist/jquery'
    },

    // Add angular modules that does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angular-route': {
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    }
});

define([
    'controllers/welcomeController',
    'bootstrap'
]);
```

bootstrap.js,

```
define([
    'require',
    'angular',
    'app'
], function (require, ng) {
    'use strict';

    require(['domReady!'], function (document) {
        ng.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
});
```

app.js,

```
define([
    'angular'
], function (ng) {
    'use strict';

    //For single module retrun.
    return ng.module('myApp', []);

});
```

But it works ok on Angular without Requirejs. I don't need to remove remove `ng-app="myApp"` from the `div`. Why?

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="scripts/vendors/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script>
            var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

            myApp.controller('welcomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.message = "Message from WelcomeController"; 
                console.log($scope.message); // It occurs only once.
            }]);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp">

            <div ng-controller="welcomeController">

                {{message}}

            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

What have I done wrong under Requirejs with Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are bootstrapping Angular twice: once with the `ng-app` directive and once with the `ng.bootstrap(...)` code in bootstrap.js! Go either for automatic (`ng-app`) or for manual (`angular.bootstrap`) bootstrapping.

Also, like Josep mentioned in his (deleted) answer, it is better to shim `angular-route` as:

```
shim: {
    'angular-route': {
        deps: ['angular']
    }
}
```

This is *NOT* the cause of the problem, but will prevent potential future problems (i.e. route being loaded before Angular).

---

[angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy/) may contain some useful ideas for Angular-RequireJS integration with lazy loading

Comment: do you mean that I should not use `ng-app` if I got for manual (angular.bootstrap) bootstrapping?

Comment: You have to keep exactly one: either `ng-app` OR `ng.bootstrap`.